# How do I use request latency as a statistic in Spinnaker automated canary analysis?

Tags: statistics, stackdriver, spinnaker

I'm using Spinnaker on Google Kubernetes Engine with Stackdriver as a log and statistics source. I'm having trouble getting timing/distribution metrics working with the Spinnaker automated canary analysis setup.

My application logs request information for each API request coming in. They include all the request details so I can create log-based stats.

A fairly truncated log entry looks like this:

```
{
  "jsonPayload": {
    "format_parameters": {
      "ElapsedMilliseconds": "4.9541",
      "Method": "POST",
      "NormalizedPath": "api/add",
      "StatusCode": "200"
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "kubernetes/labels/app.kubernetes.io/name": "calculator",
    "kubernetes/labels/track": "production",
    "kubernetes/namespace": "calculator"
  }
}
```

I've created a log-based statistic for request latency using a log filter like this:

```
resource.type="container" AND
jsonPayload.format_parameters.NormalizedPath != ""
```

And specifying it's a "Distribution" metric based on `jsonPayload.format_parameters.ElapsedMilliseconds`. I've called it `api/request_latency` and I'm able to see graphs of the data, break it down by path and request method, etc.

I want to set up Spinnaker (Kayenta) so it will fail the canary analysis if latency increases. [This article from Netflix shows they're doing that](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/automated-canary-analysis-at-netflix-with-kayenta-3260bc7acc69) but I also see they're judging it by 5th, 50th, and 99th percentiles.

I've set up my canary configuration to look at `logging.googleapis.com/user/api/request_latency` and I've got a filter like this:

```
metric.label.name="${location}" AND
metric.label.track="${scope}"
```

The `track` label switches between `canary` and `production` and the `location` is set up as the app name.

On executing the canary analysis, I get this error:

`Field aggregation.perSeriesAligner had an invalid value of "ALIGN_MEAN": The aligner cannot be applied to metrics with kind DELTA and value type DISTRIBUTION."`

I've found this is coming from Stackdriver and the Kayenta query running against the statistics [has `ALIGN_MEAN` hardcoded as the per-series aligner](https://github.com/spinnaker/kayenta/blob/c98cec125e024e814424676d5b7099a00d2db659/kayenta-stackdriver/src/main/java/com/netflix/kayenta/stackdriver/canary/StackdriverCanaryScope.java#L40).

I'm not a stats guy, and I'm honestly somewhat overwhelmed by having to figure out what things like "per-series aligner" even means.

**How do I get request latency out of my logs and use that in canary analysis?**